# Flex 4 <s:Group> Wrap <s:Label>

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I have the following example of a `<s:Group>` component within Flex 4:

```
<s:Group left="10" top="10" right="10">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout gap="20"/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:Image id="image" source="{data.imageURL}"/>
    <s:Label right="0" styleName="description" text="{data.description}"/>
</s:Group>
```

Is there a way that I can wrap the `<s:Label>` component onto a new line if it becomes too long for both the width of the image and label within the group?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the `Label` word wrap the text, it needs to have a width of some kind, so it knows where to start wrapping.

All of these labels have a width specified one way or another, and should word wrap if nec:

```
<s:Label id="fixedWidth" width="100"/>
<s:Label id="percentWidth" width="25%"/>
<s:Label id="constraintBasedWidth" left="0" right="0"/>
<s:Label id="maxWidth" maxWidth="100"/>
```

Perhaps you can try using `maxWidth` on the label. This should put it next to the image and let it wrap longer text.

There is also the [maxDisplayedLines](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/TextBase.html#maxDisplayedLines) property, which you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want `TileLayout`. That will arrange the components horizontally and wrap when it runs out of space.

Comment: I've looked into that, except I would like the image and text laid out horizontally. Is that still achievable with the `<s:TileLayout>` class?